# jquery hover fadein fadeout simultaneously

Tags: jquery, fadein, effects, fadeout

I have circle menu, which has to fadein and fadeout. Working example is here:

```
http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/
```

(only "reference" and "storitve")

first problem is that each fading waits till the last one stops. So, how do i make that if i cross from "reference" to "storitve", both fading work simultaneously?

The second problem is really strange behavior in Firefox - it runs in circles, or stops or..

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#areastoritve').hover(
        function(){
            $imgURL = "fileadmin/template/images/index/storitve.png";
                $("#ozadje")
                .fadeOut(0, function() {$("#ozadje").attr('src',$imgURL);})
                .fadeIn({ duration: 800, queue: true })
        },
        function(){
          $imgURL = "fileadmin/template/images/index/ozadjeKrog.png";
                $("#ozadje")
                .fadeOut(800, function() {$("#ozadje").attr('src',$imgURL);})
                .fadeIn({ duration: 0, queue: true })
        }
    ); 

    $('#areareference').hover(
        function(){
            $imgURL = "fileadmin/template/images/index/reference.png";
                $("#ozadje")
                .fadeOut(4, function() {$("#ozadje").attr('src',$imgURL);})
                .fadeIn(800);
        },
        function(){
          $imgURL = "fileadmin/template/images/index/ozadjeKrog.png";
                $("#ozadje")
                .fadeOut(800, function() {$("#ozadje").attr('src',$imgURL);})
                .fadeIn(4);
        }
    );  });


HTML:

<div style="width:602px; position:relative;" class="imageMap">
        <img src="images/index/ozadjeKrog.png" id="ozadje" width="602" height="602"  usemap="#image_map" border="0">

                <map name="image_map" id="image_map">
                    <area id="areastoritve" shape="poly" coords=" 300,302, 299,302, 297,301, 453,38, 491,64, 519,90, 546,123, 569,158, 585,196, 596,231, 601,258, 601,280, 601,301, 302,301" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/storitve" alt="Storitve" title="Storitve"/>
                    <area id="areaonas" shape="poly" coords=" 296,300, 150,39, 184,23, 212,14, 237,6, 264,2, 267,0, 331,1, 385,11, 418,22, 451,38, 298,297" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/o_nas" alt="O nas" title="O nas"/>
                    <area shape="poly" coords=" 296,303, 0,306, 5,250, 18,196, 40,149, 71,104, 108,70, 136,47, 148,40, 294,302" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/posamezniki" alt="Posamezniki" title="Posamezniki"/>
                    <area shape="poly" coords=" 296,307, 0,310, 0,336, 6,365, 14,396, 31,439, 58,484, 89,519, 125,549, 147,568, 292,311" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/kontakt" alt="Kontakt" title="Kontakt"/>
                    <area shape="poly" coords=" 300,308, 453,567, 419,583, 369,598, 347,601, 265,601, 208,590, 153,568, 297,310" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/galerija" alt="Galerija" title="Galerija"/>
                    <area id="areareference" shape="poly" coords=" 303,307, 458,566, 522,511, 560,462, 589,397, 601,345, 601,305, 302,305" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/reference" alt="Reference" title="Reference"/>
                </map>
        </div>
```

Comment: I still didnt find solution to the problem. I found this plugin: http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/ but i dont know how to make it work with this funcionality, maybe someoen know if this is even possibly with this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Update: See bottom for newer solution based on speaking with you.

---

Working code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/SymN8/

You need to add `stop` methods to your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. In `jQuery` this can be used to clear the current animation queue on the element you are performing the action. By adding the `stop(true,true)` to you actions this will clear the queue and only perform the last opertion.

More information here: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Here is the update code. Please note that I have added an additional DIV to hold the hover image.

`Javascript`

```
$(function(){
   $('#areastoritve').hover(
    function(){
        $imgURL = "http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/fileadmin/template/images/index/storitve.png";
            $("#ozadje2").stop(true, true)
            .fadeOut(0, function() {$("#ozadje2").attr('src',$imgURL);})
            .fadeIn({ duration: 800})
    },
          function(){
            $imgURL = "http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/fileadmin/template/images/index/ozadjeKrog.png";
            $("#ozadje2").stop(true)
            .fadeOut(800, function() {$("#ozadje2").attr('src',$imgURL);})
            .fadeIn({ duration: 0})
    }
); 

$('#areareference').hover(
    function(){
        $imgURL = "http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/fileadmin/template/images/index/reference.png";
            $("#ozadje2").stop(true)
            .fadeOut(4, function() {$("#ozadje2").attr('src',$imgURL);})
            .fadeIn(800);
    },
    function(){
      $imgURL = "http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/fileadmin/template/images/index/ozadjeKrog.png";
            $("#ozadje2").stop(true)
            .fadeOut(800, function() {$("#ozadje2").attr('src',$imgURL);})
            .fadeIn(4);
    }
);  });
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:602px; position:relative;" class="imageMap">
 <img src="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/fileadmin/template/images/index/ozadjeKrog.png" id="ozadje2" width="602" height="602"  usemap="#image_map" border="0" style="position:absolute" usemap="#image_map">
    <img src="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/fileadmin/template/images/index/ozadjeKrog.png" id="ozadje" width="602" height="602"  border="0">
<map name="image_map" id="image_map">
                <area id="areastoritve" shape="poly" coords=" 300,302, 299,302, 297,301, 453,38, 491,64, 519,90, 546,123, 569,158, 585,196, 596,231, 601,258, 601,280, 601,301, 302,301" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/storitve" alt="Storitve" title="Storitve"/>
                <area id="areaonas" shape="poly" coords=" 296,300, 150,39, 184,23, 212,14, 237,6, 264,2, 267,0, 331,1, 385,11, 418,22, 451,38, 298,297" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/o_nas" alt="O nas" title="O nas"/>
                <area shape="poly" coords=" 296,303, 0,306, 5,250, 18,196, 40,149, 71,104, 108,70, 136,47, 148,40, 294,302" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/posamezniki" alt="Posamezniki" title="Posamezniki"/>
                <area shape="poly" coords=" 296,307, 0,310, 0,336, 6,365, 14,396, 31,439, 58,484, 89,519, 125,549, 147,568, 292,311" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/kontakt" alt="Kontakt" title="Kontakt"/>
                <area shape="poly" coords=" 300,308, 453,567, 419,583, 369,598, 347,601, 265,601, 208,590, 153,568, 297,310" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/galerija" alt="Galerija" title="Galerija"/>
                <area id="areareference" shape="poly" coords=" 303,307, 458,566, 522,511, 560,462, 589,397, 601,345, 601,305, 302,305" href="http://93.103.24.208:8080/sagita/reference" alt="Reference" title="Reference"/>
            </map>
    </div>
```

---

This is as close as I can take you with your current `DOM` structure.
http://jsfiddle.net/SymN8/22/

Notice I have removed some of your methods, the image that was last selected stays selected when mouse is removed (undesired) but maybe this works for you.

Comment: Whank you for you solution. the only problem now is the transition between two menus - from fererence to storitve. When you go with mouse from reference to storitve, the animation on the first one is completely stopped, but it should continue its coure - fade out completly.. simultaneously should the next one start... I hope you undrestand what i mean?

Comment: The problem is that all of the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` operations are being performed on the same element. Ideally you would like all of these to be separated so they could be acted upon by themselves, individually so to speak.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice, but becouse the image is circle - the menu is in the circle i have to change the whole image.. So, there is no way to keep one animation going on and to start another one? I was reading about creating another queu.. but i dont get it.

Comment: See update, if it works for you let me know. I'd love to know.

Comment: Yes, i see that between two elements the fading works well.. but the undesired effect of staying selected even when the mouse is removed is not ok.. But thank you for your help.. i dont know actually how this can be acomplished..

Comment: I wish I had more time to really hash it out, I'm just scraping the surface. Sorry. If you think my answer helped feel free to accept. Have a good day. Back to work I go.

Comment: I will try for myself i ltiitle bit. thank you a lot for your help.. if i find the solution i will post it here, in any case i will accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem you need to stop(true, true) your animations before applying a new animation, this will stop the jitter effect.

Comment: But when i use .stop() the animation afcourse stops - it doesnt complet the fading proces and it doesnt looks ok, spceially when you go directly from one meni to antoher..

Comment: Pete please see my post. I have posted link to Fiddle as well to show it working. I've also altered your code a bit. As Lokase said the `stop` method is what you need. I've shown you how to use it above.